# Two scripts - read / write clash

Tags: python, ruby, file-io, dashing

I have two separate scripts, one written in Python and one in Ruby, which run on a schedule to achieve a single goal. Ruby isn't my code of choice, but it is all I can use for this task.

The Python script is run every 30 seconds,  talks to a few scientific instruments, gather certain data, writes the data to a text file (one per instrument).

The ruby script then reads these files every 20 seconds and displays the information on a dashing dashboard.

The trouble I have is that sometimes the file is being written to by Python at the same time as Ruby is trying to read it. You can see obvious problems here...

Despite putting several checks in my ruby code such as:

```
If myFile.exists? and myFile.readable? and not myFile.zero?
```

I still get these clashes every now and then.

Is there a better way in ruby to avoid reading open files / files being written to?

Comment: Take a look at the `closed?` method from IO http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/IO.html#method-i-closed-3F

Comment: That looks exactly what I'm after, however will the closed? method in Ruby still give false if it is Python has the file open?